# after setState, why console log out the old value after 1000ms?

Tags: reactjs

```
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const add = () => {
    setCounter((prev) => prev + 1);
    // old value
    console.log(counter);
    // also old value
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(counter);
    }, 1000);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{counter}</div>
      <button onClick={(e) => add()}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
```

why console log out the old value after 1000ms?

I understand why the 1st console.log prints the old value, but why the second one? I am trying to undersatan reactjs, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question？ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-does-calling-react-setstate-method-not-mutate-the-state-immediately

Comment: Yes, it helped me understand more about the life cycle mechanism. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

Because the callback function provided to your setTimeout was created using the old value of your state.

Try something like:

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const add = () => {
    setCounter((prev) => prev + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => console.log(counter), 1000);
  }, [counter])

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{counter}</div>
      <button onClick={(e) => add()}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
```

Note that if the value changes before the 1000ms you will still receive the previous value on console.

To prevent it you must cancel your timeout:

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const add = () => {
    setCounter((prev) => prev + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => console.log(counter), 1000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
  }, [counter])

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{counter}</div>
      <button onClick={(e) => add()}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Your code has helped me understand a lot, thank you.